# Django View not rendering in HTML

Tags: python, django

My views are not rendering correctly. I have the same format for both views (`index.html` and `mq.html`), and `index.html` is working fine-- it creates a bulleted list with 1 value for each bullet.

However, `mq.html` creates the correct number of bullets, but the words don't show up on the page. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code? `Models`, `Views`, and `HTML` below.

Models:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Question(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Views:

```
def index(request):
    r = Movie.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    return render_to_response('mrt2/index.html', {'latest_movie_list': r})

def movie_questions(request, movie_id):
    p = Movie.objects.get(pk=movie_id)
    k = Question.objects.filter(movie=p)
    return render_to_response('mrt2/mq.html', {'movie':p, 'the_question':k})
```

HTML:

**index.html**

```
<h1> Test </h1>

{% if latest_movie_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for movie in latest_movie_list %}
        <li><a href="/movie/{{ movie.id }}/">{{ movie.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No movies are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**mq.html**

```
{{ movie.title }}

{% if the_question %}
    <ul>
    {% for each in the_question %}
        <li><a href="/movie/{{ movie.id }}/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a>    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No questions have been asked.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for each` loop is not assigning anything to a `question`.

This:

```
{% for each in the_question %}
```

Needs to be:

```
{% for question in the_question %}
```

Comment: actually 
    {% for each question in the_question %} 
didn't work, but took out each 
    {% for question in the_question %} 
worked. thanks!

Comment: Ah, it was assigning to `each`.